# What is this hook supposed to do?

Tags: 7, hooks, views

I need to modify the query of one of my views. I've found `hook_views_query_alter()`, but can't for the life of me figure out what I'm supposed to do with it. According to the [API](http://api.drupalize.me/api/drupal/function/hook_views_query_alter/7),

> This hook should be placed in MODULENAME.views.inc and it will be
>   auto-loaded. MODULENAME.views.inc must be in the directory specified
>   by the 'path' key returned by MODULENAME_views_api(), or the same
>   directory as the .module file, if 'path' is unspecified.

OK, so I know to put the function with the hook in a views.inc file. But what do I need to put in the actual .module file? I can't seem to find any examples of complete module code that uses this hook to point me in the right direction. Does my module code contain the `MODULENAME_views_api()` and nothing else?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your module doesn't need to implement any other hooks, then yep, `hook_views_api()` is all you need in your .module file.

As long as you provide the right path in `hook_views_api()`, Views will know where to look and will dynamically include the files when they're needed.

Usually you need to put `files[] = mymodule.FILENAME.inc` in your module's .info file for the dynamic code registry to pick it up, but from the looks of it that isn't the case for Views.

If you're looking for some code examples for this, take a look at the [Administration Views](http://drupal.org/project/admin_views) module; it's .module file contains only `hook_views_api()` as well (and it works), so you can be confident you're doing the right thing.

Comment: This is the "proper" thing to do, but I don't recall a case where putting the hooks for altering queries or and of the build phases directly in a .module didn't work.

Comment: @MPD You're right it will always work in a .module file either way. Views just makes sure the file it suggests you put the hook in is included when the hook is invoked

Comment: So I could skip the .inc file entirely and just put in in the .module? My module isn't going to be doing anything other than modifying the query.

Comment: Yep, the .module file for any enabled module will be included during the bootstrap phase and views will only ever invoke the hook after that's happened. What I'm not sure of is if views expects the .inc file to be there whether or not it's got code in it. But I think you'll be able to test for that quite easily anyway

Comment: Yup, I can try it easily. So, I know this is sort of a different question, but where can I find the syntax for the various query modifiers? One of the examples I found looked like this: `$query->orderby[0] = "FIELD(node.type, 'story', 'page', 'productTypeC', 'productTypeD') ASC";` I'm not sure what that syntax is saying. Does it mean order by the node.type field, where nodes with story are first, then page, and so on? Or something else? I need to be able to group on multiple fields (and not all fields are on the initial node (relationships.)

Comment: I'm not really sure to be honest I don't use views all that often, anything I came up with would just be a guess! There are a fair few people who visit this site who know a lot about views programming though so it might be worth asking it as a separate question

Comment: The code registry is used only for classes and interfaces; it doesn't contain any information about functions. The Views module needs compatibility with previous Drupal versions, or it could have used [hook_hook_info()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_hook_info/7) to automatically load files containing hook implementations. To notice that [hook_hook_info()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21hooks%21core.php/function/hook_hook_info/6) in Drupal 6 has a completely different purpose.