# How to remove and add joins to a view?

Tags: database, views

Because of some buggy handlers I need to write a hook that will:

- Get location_instance table's alias from the original query
- Remove location_instance table join
- Remove that alias join
- Remove a location table join
- Add 2 new joins

Apparently views does things a little differently so I can't just `$query->join()` my way to freedom. How exactly do I accomplish the above?

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue I have been sturggling with myself.  You may want to start by looking at [hook_views_query_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_query_alter/7) and read this [related Drupal Answers question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/35533/hook-views-query-alter-module-code).

Then you can use these functions: [views_plugin_query_default](http://api.drupal.org/api/views/plugins!views_plugin_query_default.inc/class/views_plugin_query_default/7) to actually affect change on your query.